# Issue storing token using SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter

This is perhaps my first time working with Login and Registration in Flutter. Although that works pretty well, I'm struggling to understand why the `authentication_token` won't get stored to my local storage when I try doing so using `SharedPreferences`. Everytime I try accessing the token, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
E/flutter (16224): #0      Network.getToken
package:eatiano_app/…/network_utils/authentication.dart:18
E/flutter (16224): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16224):
D/EGL_emulation(16224): app_time_stats: avg=1023.77ms min=1.03ms max=13256.89ms count=18
D/EGL_emulation(16224): app_time_stats: avg=255.85ms min=34.01ms max=518.67ms count=4
```

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

Network Class:

```
class Network with ChangeNotifier {
  String url = 'https://achievexsolutions.in/current_work/eatiano/';
  var token;
  bool _isAuth = false;

  bool get auth {
    return _isAuth;
  }

  getToken() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // token = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('token') ?? '')['access_token'];
    token = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('token') ?? '')['token'];     //line 18
    print('Token $token');
  }

  authData(data, apiUrl) async {
    var fullUrl = url + apiUrl;
    return await http.post(Uri.parse(fullUrl),
        body: jsonEncode(data), headers: _setHeaders());
  }

  getData(apiUrl) async {
    var fullUrl = url + apiUrl;
    await getToken();          //line 30
    return await http.get(Uri.parse(fullUrl), headers: _setHeaders());
  }

  _setHeaders() => {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
      };

  checkIfLoggedIn() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    token = localStorage.getString('token');
    if (token != null) {
      _isAuth = true;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

This is the function from where I'm triggering the `getToken()` method.(This is the login function within the Login Widget)

```
void _login() async {
    final data = {'email': inputEmail, 'password': inputPassword};
    var res = await Provider.of<Network>(context, listen: false)
        .authData(data, 'api/auth/login');
    final provider =
        Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false).loading;
    print(json.decode(res.body));
    var body = json.decode(res.body);
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    localStorage.setString('token', json.encode(body['access_token']));
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/bottom-bar');
    Provider.of<Network>(context, listen: false).getToken();
  }
```

Following is the error when I try logging out:

```
E/flutter (16224): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
E/flutter (16224): #0      Network.getToken
package:eatiano_app/…/network_utils/authentication.dart:18
E/flutter (16224): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
E/flutter (16224): #0      Network.getToken
package:eatiano_app/…/network_utils/authentication.dart:18
E/flutter (16224): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16224): #1      Network.getData
package:eatiano_app/…/network_utils/authentication.dart:30
```

`authentication.dart:18` and `authentication.dart:30` are marked in comments in the Network class.

The login function:

```
child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () async {
                    var res = await Provider.of<Network>(context, listen: false)
                        .getData('api/auth/logout');
                    var body = json.decode(res.body);
                    SharedPreferences localStorage =
                        await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                    localStorage.remove('token');
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignIn()));
                  },
```

The response from the Laravel backend during login or signup:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvYWNoaWV2ZXhzb2x1dGlvbnMuaW5cL2N1cnJlbnRfd29ya1wvZWF0aWFub1wvYXBpXC9hdXRoXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0NjcyNDY2MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ3OTM0MjYwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDY3MjQ2NjAsImp0aSI6IkJaY2FjbmJZV1A1OTd0a0siLCJzdWIiOjEwLCJwcnYiOiIyM2JkNWM4OTQ5ZjYwMGFkYjM5ZTcwMWM0MDA4NzJkYjdhNTk3NmY3In0.n0M5ehm3BgP1Ctcvl_6Tt3rtYMeP1W6xgbN86LX1SLA",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "role": "user",
    "expires_in": 10596096000
}
```

Comment: First of all use `debugPrint` to find out what you are getting from `localStorage.getString('token')`. (Also avoid using `print` in applications)

Comment: ` token = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('token') ?? '')['token'];`  in `gettocken` method. here is the problem

Comment: Ah, also you don't need to jsonEncode token while saving it. Just `localStorage.setString('token', body['access_token']);` instead of `localStorage.setString('token', json.encode(body['access_token']));`. 
Then on line 18 use simple `localStorage.getString('token')`, dont decode it. No need to make things more complicated.

Comment: @lava Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
var decode = jsonDecode('{"access_tocken":"${localStorage.getString('tocken') ?? ''}"}')['access_tocken'];
    print(decode);
```

Modify you gettocken method

```
 getToken() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // token = jsonDecode('{"access_tocken":"${localStorage.getString('tocken') ?? ''}"}')['access_tocken'];
    token = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('token') ?? '')['token'];     //line 18
    print('Token $token');
  }
```

**Problem:**

But you trying like this .`jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('tocken') ??'')` it is not json structure to decode `localStorage.getString('tocken')` return string not a json string so you coud'nt access .`jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('tocken') ??'')['access_tocken']`

```
 var decode = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('tocken') ??'')['access_tocken'];
print(decode);
    //output 
     type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```